# Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson' on Mac

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, mongodb, google-chrome

I am using node.js to run one app given by my professor on my chrome. Something wrong happen, but I don't know because I am a rookie. 
The structure is as follows:

```
/app
   /models
      answers.js
      questions.js
      sessions.js
      user.js
   passport.js
   qmanage.js
   routes.js
/config
   auth.js
   database.js
   mcd.js
package.json
/public
   some css png fonts jpg document
qloader.js
server.js
/views
   some ejs document
```

At first, it shows this problem:

```
module.js:457
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'mongoose'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/shen/Desktop/os/cse303.p2/server.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
```

then, based on this help [Node.js error Error: Cannot find module 'mongoose'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623205/node-js-error-error-cannot-find-module-mongoose) I run `npm install mongoose` in my root path of project. Then I have those error below:

```
dyn143030:cse shen$ node server.js 
{ Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/shen/Desktop/os/cse303.p2/node_modules/bson/ext/index.js:15:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Invalid mongodb uri. Missing hostname
    at muri (/Users/shen/Desktop/os/cse303.p2/node_modules/muri/lib/index.js:40:11)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.open (/Users/shen/Desktop/os/cse303.p2/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:195:16)
    at Mongoose.connect (/Users/shen/Desktop/os/cse303.p2/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:212:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/shen/Desktop/os/cse303.p2/server.js:4:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:590:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

I tried to find solution from this help
[Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' } js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651028/cannot-find-module-build-release-bson-code-module-not-found-js-bson)
but it seems not my case, because I am using OS X 10.11.3

```
dyn143030:cse shen$ node -v
v6.5.0
dyn143030:cse shen$ npm -v
3.10.3
```

From my aspect, I think the system find bson someplace wrong, so how to modify it? Thanks! If any more information is need, please tell me.

Comment: Have you tried doing `npm update` just to make sure things are all updated?

Comment: I just tried that, but useless

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I find in node_modules\bson\ext\index.js

and change path on 10th line

`bson = require('../build/Release/bson');` to `bson = require('bson');`

Comment: Editing anything under node_modules is a nasty hack.

Comment: I would not recommend changing modules.
I deploy to Heroku and all the modules get installed by reading package.json.

Answer (score -1):

You can try adding mongoose to the dependency list in the package.json file, or also doing >npm install mongoose in the project folder.